# Как остановить скольжение прокрутки при переходе на другой таб?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tabs

**Environment:**

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.11.0"
```

**Problem:**

Как остановить прокрутку скольжения при переходе на другой таб?

**Example:**

Когда я прокручиваю контент и убираю свой палец с экрана, то контент продолжает прокручиваться, то есть скользить. Мне надо, чтобы когда я переходил на другую вкладку, то это скольжение прокрутки мгновенно останавливалось. То есть контент в той вкладке не прокручивался в фоновом режиме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {FlatList, Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {TabView, SceneMap} from 'react-native-tab-view';

const DATA = Array.from(Array(1000).keys());

const renderFlatList = () => {
  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return <Text>{index}</Text>;
  };

  const keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

  return (
    <FlatList data={DATA} renderItem={renderItem} keyExtractor={keyExtractor} />
  );
};
const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, {backgroundColor: '#ff4081'}]}>
    {renderFlatList()}
  </View>
);

const SecondRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, {backgroundColor: '#673ab7'}]}>
    {renderFlatList()}
  </View>
);

export default class TabViewExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [{key: 'first', title: 'First'}, {key: 'second', title: 'Second'}],
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TabView
          navigationState={this.state}
          renderScene={SceneMap({
            first: FirstRoute,
            second: SecondRoute,
          })}
          onIndexChange={index => this.setState({index})}
          initialLayout={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 36,
  },
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте при переходе на другую вкладку `FlatLis` передать:

```
scrollEnabled={false}
```

Comment: Это не работает. Когда мы задаем импульс прокрутки у первой вкладки и переходим на другую вкладку, то у первой вкладки прокрутка все равно скользит, без разницы передаем ли мы scrollEnabled как false.